# Validity Fingerprint 138a:0090 reader

Tags: elementary-project

wondering if anyone has got the Validity Fingerprint reader 138a:0090 working with elementary OS? I'm running 5.1.6 and a noob. Have fumbled through the instructions found here: [https://launchpad.net/~3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/libfprint-vfs0090](https://launchpad.net/%7E3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/libfprint-vfs0090)

Seems like I may be missing something, or have done things out of sequence. (first tried installing fprint demo, via the Appcenter). Have been able to initialise the reader with validity-sensors-tools but that is as far as I can get. When running Fingerprint GUI, the message: no devices found! appears.

Any pointers would be very welcome, especially from anyone who has got this working.

My machine is the ThinkPad X1.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, have got fingerprint authentication working now in Hera 5.1, with the Thinkpad X1. Maybe others will be luckier than me, but following the instructions on https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint did not work for me. I tried many variations, but always the same error with fingerprint-gui and fprint-demo: No Device Found.

While this method works, it will not work with either of those GUI applications.

Huge thanks to sysadmin here, @himekifee over on Gitter, and Marco Trevisan for his work on all this.

Here are the steps to get things working.

**Install snap:**

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

**Install Validity tools and initialise the device:**

```
sudo snap install validity-sensors-tools
sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:raw-usb
sudo snap connect validity-sensors-tools:hardware-observe
sudo validity-sensors-tools.initializer
```

**Compile libfprint:**

```
git clone https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint
meson libfprint libfprint/_build && sudo ninja -C libfprint/_build install
```

**Install libfprint**

**Install fprintd**

Install fprintd from focal release 20.04: (the bionic version would not work)

```
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main restricted universe' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-focal.list

echo 'APT::Default-Release "bionic"' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01ubuntu-bionic

sudo apt-get install -y -t focal fprintd
```

**Install PAM:**

```
sudo apt-get install libpam0g-dev libpam-fprintd
```

**Configure PAM:**

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Include fingerprint reader as authentication option. Click ok.

```
Update symbolic link /usr/lib/libfprint.so.0 -> /usr/local/lib/libfprint.so.0.0.0 (to libfprint)
```

**Allow fingerprint enrolling to user:**

Create /lib/udev/rules.d/40-libfprint0-custom.rules as follows:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="138a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0090", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev"

**Add your $USER to plugdev group:**

usermod -a -G plugdev $USER
```

Reboot

**Enroll fingerprints:**

```
fprintd-enroll
```

**Verify fingerprint matching:**

```
fprintd-verify
```

**Add fingerprint authentication configuration for login:**

Edit /etc/pam.d/common-auth for editing (sudo nano /etc/pam.d/common-auth).

Add: first line

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
```

Can also edit /etc/pam.d/sudo (include at the top):

```
auth    sufficient  pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth    sufficient  pam_fprintd.so
```

**Good resources:**

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Login_configuration
- https://launchpad.net/%7E3v1n0/+archive/ubuntu/libfprint-vfs0090
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049526/fingerprint-activation-on-ubuntu-18-04
- https://gitter.im/Validity90/Lobby

Comment: Upvoted. Excellent work.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install fprint_demo
```

I guess the last command, because I do not know the name of the package.

The second solution is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120849/installing-libfprint-0-99-0-using-meson-and-ninja

However I would like to ask you to open terminal and type:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And check does it show missing firmware.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've followed the steps above, but the device is not found by fprint_demo. I tried the sudo update-initramfs -u command, but there are no values returned. 
I also tried running dmesg and the output related to the validity reader is: 

[    3.829596] usb 1-9: New USB device found, idVendor=138a, idProduct=0090, bcdDevice= 1.64

I'm thinking that this means the driver has not been loaded.

Comment: Exactly. Give me two days, I will look for the driver and will provide guide how to install it.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you! I've been trying various things and continue to research, but have not been able to solve this yet. I'm very new to Linux, so it's been a good learning experience.

Comment: Hi Sysadmin, did you get a chance to have a look? I've kept trying, but cannot get the fprind-demo to see the device.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/756706/install-fingerprint-driver-138a0090-on-ubuntu-16-04-thinkpad-t460s See this. Barro32 provided solution.

Comment: Thanks @sysadmin. Have also tried this. No joy. This is driving me nuts .

Comment: have made headway. Compiled libfprint-vfs0090, installed > fprintd still not picking up sensor. Installed version 1.90 from focal and now picks up sensor, can enroll and verify by bash, but still fprint-demo and fingerprint-gui do not recognise the device, so basically unusable. Any hints?

Comment: The only one idea I have is to go to this github and give it a try and eventually ask the owner of this git for a help. https://github.com/3v1n0/libfprint

Comment: Thanks @Syadmin. Further good progress as have now got sudo working with fprintd. pam.d is needed to work together with fprintd. This article has been helpful. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fprint#Login_configuration Should nail it by the end of the week and happy to document everything for other elementary users if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got closer to finding the issue with this. I've tried this:

purged everything fprint related, rebooted and started from scratch.

```
Initialised with validity tools
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:3v1n0/libfprint-vfs0090
sudo apt-get update
Reboot
sudo apt install fprint_demo
```

Rebooted and ran dpkg -l '*fprint*'

The output is without errors:

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                  Version         Architecture    Description
+++-=====================-===============-===============-================================================
ii  fprint-demo           20080303git-6   amd64           simple GTK+ testing libfprint's functions
ii  libfprint0            1:0.7.0-git2018 amd64           fingerprint library of fprint project, shared li

Ran lsusb and the output includes the fingerprint sensor:
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0090 Validity Sensors, Inc.

I think this tells me the sensor is recognised by the system, however fprint-demo (and fingerprint gui) do not recognise the device.

Running fprint-demo and still get 'no devices found'.

I then found these instructions:

You need to add a new udev 110 rule to allow access to the device.
My rule was ATTRS{idVendor}=="138a", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0011", MODE="0664", GROUP="plugdev" but you need to change some parameters.
GROUP must be a group your user is in.
ATTRS{idVendor}:ATTRS{idProduct} describe your device and can be found with lsusb

However, this is the extent of my knowledge and unsure how to follow these instructions. Will keep chipping away at it.